# Big O notation in python

Tags: python, big-o, notation

Does anyone know of any good resources to learn big o notation? In particular learning how to walk through some code and being able to see that it would be O(N^2) or O(logN)? Preferably something that can tell me why a code like this is equal to O(N log N)

```
def complex(numbers):
    N = len(numbers)
    result = 0
    for i in range(N):
        j = 1
        while j < N:
            result += numbers[i]*numbers[j]
            j = j*2
    return result
```

Thanks!

Comment: It's not about "code"、"program" or language ,it's about algorithm.

Comment: @Porcelain ahh ok, but do you know of any good websites that can help? Kinda like a crash course on it?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy whoops sorry, O( N log N )

Answer (score 1):

To start, let me define to you what O(N log N) is. It means, that the program will run at most N log N operations, i.e. it has a upper bound of ~N log N (where N is the size of the input).

Now here, your N is the size of numbers, or your code:

```
N = len(numbers)
```

Notice that the first for loop runs from 0 to N-1, for a total of N operations. This is where the first N comes from.

-

Then, where does the log N come from? It is from the while loop.

In the while loop, you keep multiplying 2 to j until j is greater or equal than N.

This will be completed when we have executed the loop ~log2(N) times, which describes how many times we have to multiply j by 2 to get to N. For example, log2(8) = 3, because we multiply j by 2 three times to get 8:

```
#ofmult. j      oldj
  1      2  2 <- 1 * 2
  2      4  4 <- 2 * 2
  3      8  8 <- 4 * 2
```

To better illustrate this, I have added a print statement in your code, for i and j:

```
def complex(numbers):
    N = len(numbers)
    result = 0
    for i in range(N):
        j = 1
        while j < N:
            print(str(i) + " " + str(j))
            result += numbers[i]*numbers[j]
            j = j*2
    return result
```

When this is run:

```
>>> complex([2,3,5,1,5,3,7,3])
```

This is what is outputted:

```
0 1
0 2
0 4
1 1
1 2
1 4
2 1
2 2
2 4
3 1
3 2
3 4
4 1
4 2
4 4
5 1
5 2
5 4
6 1
6 2
6 4
7 1
7 2
7 4
```

Notice how our i goes from 0...7 (N times for a total of O(N) ), and the second part, there are always 3 ( log2(N) ) j-outputs for every i.
So, the code is O(N log2 N).

Also, some good websites I would recommend are:
https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

And, a video from a lecture series from a Stanford professor:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNsKNfFUqFo

Comment: It means, that the program will run at most at most **C times N log N**, where C is some constant.

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply j by 2, you're effectively saying "I've done half the remaining problem!". At each step in the while loop, you're solving half the remaining problem. Therefore if your problem is `x` size, then the number of iterations required would be `i = log_2 x`, which we just say is `log x`. In this case your x is just equal to N.

The for loop has you do the above section N times again, so you get N * log N.

We use O(N log N) to mean that, at each step, we might do any CONSTANT number of things (for example inside the while loop I might do a billion operations), but we don't care about this constant, because generally N is usually bigger, and can get arbitrarily big (beyond a certain size point, even a billion is nothing in comparison to what N COULD be, i.e. a googol). Hence we have O(N log N).

Here's a short crash course in the form of a pdf:

http://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/~barath/cs61b-summer2002/lectures/lecture10.pdf

Here's a short crash course in the form of a lecture:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIS4YDpuP98

Comment: both are dead links as of March 2019